# How to determine the status of an AQjmsDestination?

Tags: oracle, advanced-queuing

We are using JMS to process messages in a Java 1.8 SE environment, using an underlying Oracle (12) Advanced Queue.  On can start a queue, specifying whether enqueueing and dequeuing are allowed using:

```
(AQjmsDestination)queue.start(q_sess, true, true);
```

The second argument indicates whether enqueueing is enabled, while the third argument indicates whether dequeueing is enabled.  However, if we are given an `AQjmsDestination` object, I don't see how to determine whether enqueuing or dequeueing are enabled from within Java.  Does anybody know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to make a simple JMS call to determine whether or not enqueueing and dequeueing are allowed.  You can get that information from the database, using a query like:

```
 Select name, enqueue_enabled, dequeue_enabled from user_queues
 Where queue_type='NORMAL_QUEUE' and name = 'my_queue_name';
```

So, for now, I am wrapping that query up in JDBC to get the information I need.